# EF Core Include multiple inherited types TPH

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

### The problem

**Query BaseClass and Include information from derived types.**

For example: Base class **Offer** has two types one with a Card only (**CardOffer**) and with Multiple Cards (**CarouselOffer**).

**Question:** How to query the BaseClass and Include the information from the derived types CardOffer and CarouselOffer? In the manner shown below:

```
    _dbContext.Offers.Include(...).ToList();
```

Currently I solved this by querying each inherited type

```
        var cards = await _dbContext.CardOffers
            .Include(c => c.Card)
            .ToListAsync();

        var carousels = await _dbContext.CarouselOffers
            .Include(c => c.Cards)
            .ToListAsync();
        
        List<Offer> offers = new List<Offer>();
        offers.AddRange(cards);
        offers.AddRange(carousels);
```

But this is far from optimal.

**Additional Information:** Below I added a diagram to show the Database and my code sample:
[image: DB Diagram]

### The Code:

**Offer** class

```
public abstract class Offer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Discrimnator { get; set; }

    public ClientUser ClientUser { get; set; }
}
```

**CardOffer** class:

```
public class CardOffer : Offer
{
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

**CarouselOffer** class:

```
public class CarouselOffer : Offer
{
    public ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

**Card** class:

```
public class Card
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public string Category { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
}
```

FluentApi:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Offers)
            .WithOne(u => u.ClientUser)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discrimnator");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CardOffer>()
            .HasOne(u => u.Card);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarouselOffer>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Cards);
```

Comment: Currently not supported. Coming with [EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#include-for-derived-types)